# Difference between explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis in MongoDB and SHOW PROFILES in MariaDB

Tags: mongodb, mariadb, profiling

I am writing a python script to compare the performance of MariaDB and MongoDB with regards to a number of queries but I am not sure how can I get comparable measures of execution time. I though instead of timing the execution of my script, I should fetch the execution time directly from the data stores.
In case of MariaDB, the last row of SHOW PROFILES would give me the time it took to execute the last query and, for MongoDB, .explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis would give the equivalent. However, I am no sure if they are really comparable. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Why don't you time the entire operation in your application?

Comment: This is actually my current setup, However, I believe that when I compare the execution times, the relative differences will be messed up with the network delay.